# PowerShell - empty deleted items and junk folder

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am using the following code to empty my deleted items and junk folders as it was full. But in the server it holds some data which is not deleting either through the script or by cleaning up the folders. Can some one let me know how can I clean up the two folders as the space was running out.

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(3)
$readItems = $inbox.Items
$readItems | ForEach-Object{ $_.Delete() }
$junkEmail = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(23)
$junkItems = $junkEmail.Items
$junkItems | ForEach-Object{ $_.Delete() }
```